# Create card swipe animation in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to make it so when I swipe left the card will follow your finger while you swipe it across the screen, changing the `translateX`. I left out a lot of code as to not distract you. Thanks!

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <GestureRecognizer
      onSwipeLeft={async () => {
        let pokemon = await fetchPokemon();
        while (pokemon == 'error') {
          pokemon = await fetchPokemon();
          if (pokemon != 'error') {
            break;
          }
        }
        setPokemonInfo(pokemon); 
      }}
    style={styles.gestureContainer}
    >
      <Animated.View style={styles.container}>
        <Card>
          <View style={styles.pokemonImg} >
            <SvgUri width="120" height="120"
              source={{
                uri: pokemonInfo.img
              }}
            />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.pokemonName}>{pokemonInfo.name}</Text>
        </Card>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </Animated.View>
    </GestureRecognizer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    transform: [{translateX: 0}]
  },

});
```

Comment: there is no need to use gesture recognizer make your card view a horizontal scrollview and then you can get the required behavior with interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swiper. It's pretty simple to use.